# Is it possible to bind Kendo UI widgets to PouchDB database?

Tags: kendo-ui, couchdb, pouchdb

[PouchDB database](http://pouchdb.com/) can be used as both local persistence storage and remote
protocol that syncs with server.

Kendo UI widgets like Kendo Grid use DataSource object to be bound to remote (CouchDB) or local data storage .

Is it possible to abstract PouchDB database with Kendo Datasource, and use PouchDB with Kendo UI widgets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a library that acts as adapter between Kendo DataSource and PouchDB database, here's the link:

https://github.com/terikon/kendo-pouchdb

You can use following code to initialize DataSource that binds to PouchDB database:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    type: "pouchdb",
    transport: {
        pouchdb: {
            db: db,
            idFactory: function (data) {
                return data.ProductID;
            }
        }
    });
```

Here's [demo](http://terikon.github.io/kendo-pouchdb/demo/kendo-pouchdb-grid.html).